# Unable to access writeresult from remove() in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm pretty new to Mongodb and have so far successfully used `Find, Insert, Update` methods. However, with `Delete` function I am not able to access **WriteResult**

**Insert** (*Works*)

```
productCollection.insert(newProduct, function (err, result) {
        callBack(err, { message: result["insertedCount"] + ' product created successfully.' });
    });
```

**Find** (*Works*)

```
productCollection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        callBack(err, { product: docs });
    });
```

**Delete** (Has Issues)

```
productCollection.remove({ id: pId }, { justOne: 1 }, function (err, result) {
      callBack(err, { message: result});
});
```

Here when I return **{message: result}** I get

```
{
    "message": {
        "ok": 1,
        "n": 0
    }
}
```

But I want to actually read "n" from Result to show no of documents deleted

Tried following

1. { message: result["n"] }
2. { message: result["nRemoved"] }

But in both cases it returns empty object {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Yelizaveta for pointing out the deprecated method. However in my case, following worked

```
productCollection.removeOne({ id: pId }, { w: 1 }, function (err, r) {
    callBack(err, { message: r.result["n"]});
});
```

I could not get **r.result.n** working instead **r.result["n"]** worked, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

According to the 2.0 version of Node.js MongoDB Driver API, remove() method is deprecated, you can use removeOne() method instead:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#remove

In order to receive number of documents that were removed, you need to use safe mode to ensure removal of documents. To do this, specify write concern by passing {w: 1} to removeOne() function:

```
productCollection.removeOne({ _id: pId }, { w:1 }, function(err, r) {
  // number of records removed: r.result.n
  callBack(err, { message: r });
});
```

Hope this helps.